# IIS High Thread Count

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have an IIS application which behaves like this - Number of total threads in IIS processes is low, traffic starts at some low rate like 5 rpm, the number of threads starts increasing, alarmingly, keeps on going even after load stops, does not gets down in reasonable time, reaches like 30,000 plus threads,  response time goes for a toss.

Machine config is set to auto_Config.

There are no explicit threads in application, though there is some --very fancy-- use of parallel for each.

Looking for some tips on how do I go about diagnosing this. Reducing parallel for each seemed to help; I am yet to conclusively prove it. Limiting max number of threads also helps cap the thread count; but I am thinking that there is something wrong with the app that causes those threads to keep increasing. I would want to solve this.

In the picture below, the thread count is ONLY for IIS worker processes. The PUT requests are the only ones doing some work; gets are mostly static resources requests.

[image]

Comment: Which monitoring tool is that on your screenshot?

Comment: DataDog monitoring tool. I cross checked the high thread count in TaskManager/Resource Monitor also.

Comment: Such data are useless to determine the cause, but help show the exact symptoms. If you can run a performance profiler you can track down what each threads do and then locate the cause. If not, hang dump analysis can help. There is no simple answer to such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be reproduced in a local or dev environment?   If so it's a good time to attach to the process and use the debugging tools to see what threads are managed and where they are in code.  If that fails to unveil anything then it might be a time to capture a memory dump from the process and dig into it with windbg.